# navigationItem.searchController Behavior is different from ios12

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem, ios13

In iOS12 the navigationItem.searchController should show when push down and hide on push up. bug in ios13, it can show, but never hide, unless your list is longer than the screen, below is my code, it work fine in ios12:

```
_searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
_searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
_searchController.searchBar.placeholder = SP_LOCSTR(@"Search");
_searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
_searchController.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.searchController = _searchController;
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
```

Comment: did you find out the answer to this?

Comment: The iOS13 search controller behavior has changed substantially from iOS12 and is causing me and others many problems - suggest checking out the WWDC event that gives an overview of changes to search controller, but this doesn't mention fundamental changes that I can't get around, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/